# Instagram JavaScript SDK issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, instagram

I'm try to use

```
https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-javascript-sdk
```

library to access instagram api but when I try to use this code:

```
 IG.init({
client_id: "e40f15***d8a66",
check_status: true, // check and load active session
cookie: true // persist a session via cookie
 });
```

appears ever this error:

```
Cannot read property 'init' of null
```

Comment: The appropriate script/API is probably not being loaded (check the browser's network log), or IG.init code is running too soon.

Comment: ^ this is correct. Basically IG isn't defined at that point.